# Building a stand-alone python library with dependencies using Cython

Tags: python, dll, shared-libraries, cython

I've a program written in Python called 'Tradutor' that i want to make a stand-alone library. The program have these dependencies: `numpy`, `matplotlib`, `pyyaml`, `nltk`, and `aelius`. My lib interface is defined on `ModuleTranslate.py`:

```
from Tradutor import *

tradutor = Tradutor()

def iniciar(x):
 return tradutor.traduzir(x)
```

And i want to build a library (.so/.dll) using Cython to generate a `ModuleTranslate.so` that i can just import this lib into Python without any dependency (`numpy`, `matplotlib`, etc) and works fine, just like this example:

```
import ModuleTranslate

r = iniciar("Test")
```

I've searched a lot for a solution but i'm in trouble with the `setup.py`. Can someone help me with the solution for this dependencies? Any tutorial or discussion it will be very welcome!

Comment: can you please provide what you have for your setup.py.  It might help if we got a look what it to see what you've tried doing.  Also, i'm still a bit confused.  Are you trying to create a module that can be install via pip for example or some kind of standalone like py2exe and py2app?

Comment: @hrand What I want is to be able to run in this Python module on any computer without the dependencies that he needed, just a `import ModuleTranslate` and ready. For generate the setup.py, i've found this tutorial https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/PackageHierarchy

Comment: If you build it for pypi any computer can install it via the pip command. You just have to use the pypi setup file and research how to set up a file for the pypi database.